# Is ID required for visiting the war cemeteries in Cowra?

Tags: australia, new-south-wales

Wikitravel's [Japanese-language guide to New South Wales](https://wikitravel.org/ja/%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A6%E3%82%B9%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A7%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%82%BA%E5%B7%9E) (Japanese hasn't yet migrated to Wikivoyage), appears to claim that a Japanese passport is required for Japanese citizens to visit the Japanese war cemetery in Cowra:

> カウラ ( Cowra ) ー カウラ日本人墓地とカウラ日本庭園がある。日本人墓地に入るには、日本国パスポートの提示が必要。

Google translate:

> Cowra - Cowra There are Japanese cemetery and Cowra Japanese garden. To enter the Japanese cemetery, presentation of the Japanese passport is necessary.

By contrast, [Visit Cowra](https://visitcowra.com.au/cowra-war-cemetries/) says about the Japanese war cemetery:

> Accessible at all times and admission is free

and there's no mention of any restrictions on the [Trip Advisor page](https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Attraction_Review-g261613-d577843-Reviews-Japanese_War_Cemetery-Cowra_New_South_Wales.html).

Are non-Japanese allowed to visit the cemetery, and are there any ID requirements for visiting the place?

Comment: FWIW, [the Wikitravel article was last modified in 2014](https://wikitravel.org/wiki/ja/index.php?title=%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A6%E3%82%B9%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A7%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%82%BA%E5%B7%9E&diff=150392&oldid=123363) with this addition only. While researching about this, I stumbled upon a Q&A in 2012 on [Yahoo! Chiebukuro (Japanese)](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1483936034) that states "Cowra Japanese Cemetery is considered as Japan's territory (national treasure), but *Japanese still needs passport to enter*"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are definitely no citizenship, age, or ID requirements for entering the Japanese cemetery and gardens.  It's been several years since I was there, but realistically there is no way such restrictions would ever be enforced - plus they would almost certainly be illegal under Australian law (discrimination on grounds of race/citizenship).

I suspect this is a case of something being lost in the translation - perhaps to "enter" the cemetery (ie, be buried there) you had to "present a Japanese passport" (ie, be Japanese)?

Comment: Or perhaps Japanese people need a Japanesa passport to enter Australia and visit the cemetery.